# Android: download image from webserver through php

Tags: php, android, image, download

I want to download an image from an android app. However, in the app I don't know the name of the image.

In a php script, I choose the image file that the app should download randomly and now I have two options:

1. I could echo the image file name and the app can then download the file directly
2. I could just echo the whole image data

What is the better way? And if it is the first, could you link to a good page on how to download an image? I can upload images easily but the internet is full of different ways on how to download an image, so I don't know which one is the best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i did it was the first way, the image URL was stored in a database and retrieved through json along with other data, the i used the below code to get the image from the URL.

```
public class ImageDownloader {

public static Bitmap downloadImage(String url) throws MalformedURLException{
    return downloadImage(new URL(url));
}

public static Bitmap downloadImage(URL url){
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    try {
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }


    return bmImg;
 }  
}
```

Comment: but what I was wondering is if there is a disadvantage to just echoing the image data? Because I need to delete the image from the server after having downloaded it, this would be much easier with just echoing. Then it could be done in one go. With your method, you would have to request the image url, then download the image and then call a php script which deletes the image. If someone closed the app in between, that wouldn't be very good....

Comment: Well it sound like you should just echo the image data. In my app, i wanted to show other info from the server while the image was downloading so this was the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It returns bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getImage(String url){
        Bitmap img = null ;
        try {
            URL feedImage = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)feedImage.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img ;    
    }
```